# What are the specialities of each Pikmin type in Pikmin Bloom?

Tags: pikmin-bloom

When I unlocked purple Pikmin, the message said that they are strong; and indeed, when I send them on expeditions, they increase the applied strength markedly:
[image]

I assume that this means that the other types of Pikmin must also have specialities in the game.  What are they best at?

Comment: in the main games, the red pikmin could withstand fire and have slightly stronger attack, yellow pikmin can fly farther and have electric affinity, blue pikmin can survive in water, purple are super strong, and white are very fast with poison resistance. I haven't played pikmin bloom yet, but experiment to see if these traits are reflected?

Comment: Reds are punching harder in the mushrooms I found out. Not sure about the whites (and further) yet, as I don't have those at level 4.

Comment: @Mathias711 I think it is that you get an advantage on the mushrooms if the colours match - so reds are better at red mushrooms, blues are better at blue mushrooms, etc.  I might be wrong though

Comment: @Margaret I've seen similar things indeed. And I also think that 'fed'/plucked Pikmin are stronger. Also if they have an outfit they seem to be stronger